# Bad coding habit wanted

Tags: emulation

Hey I'm currently trying to emulate an old gaming console. I'm run into a little problem that I do not know how to fix.

More specific, I'm doing a emulator for a GBA. But to make it a little more challenging, I have decided to emulate the games as external devices with memory, possible extra CPUs and such. Just like they are in the real world. To do this I need to create a self contained executable file, where there is allocated some fix size spare memory to save data like saved games.

Is this possible? I know this is uncommon and bad habit. I don't care, it is like people saying DON'T USE GOTO in C, the instruction are there to be used, and I use it with good effect an no headache, and no weird behaviour, it just takes a moment of planning, and maybe a course in compiler implementation to know how.

The language are not important, C will do, but if .net supported it I'll prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the approach used by some self-extracting archives.  Append a marker GUID and a data block after the compiled executable

(executable file) + (marker GUID) + (data area)

In Windows for example, using a command box:

```
type "c:\vsprojects\my-gba\release\my-gba.exe" "c:\data-files\guid.txt" "c:\data-files\save-data-area.txt" > "c:\data-files\gba-combo.exe"
```

In Linux you'd cat the 3 pieces together into a new file to form your executable-with-data.

To find the start of the data area, you search for the GUID in the EXE and then seek past it.

There is a very slight chance the GUID could occur naturally in your code, but the odds of that become extremely low the longer the GUID gets.  You can use an online GUID generator and combine multiple strings in the GUID text file for example

```
731056dd-1dd7-4f46-b90b-2ad623198404 a2d0cd76-f8fc-4bcf-8a15-80ca4d9b205f
```

You do need to make sure you don't write your code in a way that embeds the GUID as a string constant earlier in your code, before the appended marker.

BAD:

```
const char* foo = "731056dd-1dd7-4f46-b90b-2ad623198404 a2d0cd76-f8fc-4bcf-8a15-80ca4d9b205f"
-- code that seeks for foo ---
```

OK:

```
const char* arr[] = { "731056dd-1dd7-4f46-b90b-2ad623198404", "BREAK-MATCH", "a2d0cd76-f8fc-4bcf-8a15-80ca4d9b205f" };
-- code sets foo from arr [0], " ", [2] then seeks for foo ---
```

Comment: Your code does know where to find it, you seek for the GUID then seek + (length of GUID) then that is the offset of your file that is the data area.  You only need to seek once at startup to find the right offset.

Comment: thanks. Couldn't it technically be done by making an array with spare bytes which are global, and set the bytes from where I wish the data should be stored to the GUID? then i search as you suggested but no need to alter the file afterward?

Comment: That might work but I haven't tried it.  We do it the way I describe above at work because we need to append a zip file of unknown size.